# How to show latest dates range for every user and filter period by custom condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below table structure

```
UserID | Date
1        2020-01-01
1        2020-01-02
1        2020-01-03
1        2020-02-05
1        2020-02-06
1        2020-03-08
1        2020-03-09
2        2020-01-02
2        2020-01-03
2        2020-01-04
2        2020-01-18
2        2020-01-19
2        2020-01-20
2        2020-02-03
2        2020-02-04
2        2020-02-05
2        2020-02-09
2        2020-02-10
2        2020-02-11
2        2020-02-12
2        2020-02-13
2        2020-02-14
2        2020-02-15
2        2020-02-16
3        2020-01-02
3        2020-01-03
3        2020-03-15
3        2020-03-16
3        2020-03-17
3        2020-03-20
3        2020-03-21
```

Desired result:

```
UserID | Date
1        2020-03-08
1        2020-03-09
2        2020-02-03
2        2020-02-04
2        2020-02-05
2        2020-02-09
2        2020-02-10
2        2020-02-11
2        2020-02-12
2        2020-02-13
2        2020-02-14
2        2020-02-15
2        2020-02-16
3        2020-03-15
3        2020-03-16
3        2020-03-17
3        2020-03-20
3        2020-03-21
```

So I need to show latest dates range for every user but if difference between last date ranges is > 7 need to hide such rows.

As an example here dates for user 2.

```
2        2020-01-02
2        2020-01-03
2        2020-01-04
2        2020-01-18
2        2020-01-19
2        2020-01-20
2        2020-02-03
2        2020-02-04
2        2020-02-05
2        2020-02-09
2        2020-02-10
2        2020-02-11
2        2020-02-12
2        2020-02-13
2        2020-02-14
2        2020-02-15
2        2020-02-16
```

Results will be

```
2        2020-02-03
2        2020-02-04
2        2020-02-05
2        2020-02-09
2        2020-02-10
2        2020-02-11
2        2020-02-12
2        2020-02-13
2        2020-02-14
2        2020-02-15
2        2020-02-16
```

The latest date before 2020-02-03 for user 2 is 2020-01-20. Date difference between them more than 7 days  so need to filter all rows before 2020-02-03 for user 2.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this below- option-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1256930c9e4982e01d34fe168b8a528b)

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT *,
    DATEDIFF(DD,LAG(Date) OVER(PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY date),Date) DD
    FROM your_table
)

SELECT UserID,Date 
FROM CTE A
WHERE 1 > 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM CTE B 
    WHERE B.DD >= 7 -- You can check by changing to >7 to meet your req
    AND B.UserID = A.UserID 
    AND B.Date > A.Date 
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Work perfectly

Comment: Nice to hear that. Please don't forget to give an up vote as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions.  Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(case when prev_date < dateadd(day, -7, date) or prev_date is null
                      then date
                 end) over (partition by userId order by date) as min_date
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(date) over (partition by userId order by date) as prev_date
            from t
           ) t
      ) t
where date >= min_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Using aggregation inside `exists`

```
 with cte as

(select *, case when datediff(dd,lag(date) over (partition by userid order by date), date) >7 
                then date end as date2
 from your_table)

select a.* 
from your_table a
where exists (select 1 
              from cte b 
              group by userid 
              having a.date>=max(b.date2) and a.userid=b.userid)
```